# Why is (/ 1/2) in Clojure equal to 2N?

Tags: clojure, division, bigint

Just playing around in the Clojure repl the other day and I came across this.

```
user=> (/ 1/2)
2N
```

So I tried this:

```
user=> (type (/ 1/2)) 
clojure.lang.BigInt
```

Anybody know what's going on here?

Answer (score 5):

1/2 creates a `Ratio` and the `/` function ends up calling `(clojure.lang.Numbers/divide 1 1/2)`. If you look at that definition it eventually ends up calling `(clojure.lang.Numbers$RatioOps/divide 1 1/2)`. This lifts `1L` into a ratio, performs the ratio division and then simplifies the result of `2/1` into the `BigInt` 2.

Comment: Note that a [`clojure.lang.Ratio`](http://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Ratio.java), holds the `numerator` and `denominator` as Java `Biginteger`s. Hence the subsequent inversion can't easily be reduced to a `long`, even if it could be.